# How to flatten packages in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, view, package, explorer, flat

I'm trying to create a flattened project hierarchy in eclipse 4.2 Juno - this is the latest version at time of writing.

I've enabled **Package Presentation -> Flat** in **Package Explorer** yet this has made no difference, the view is still hierarchical.

I cannot find any plugins which offer an improved package navigation experience. I simply desire the most productive configuration, i.e. a layout with no unnecessary clicking of expand/collapse arrows!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the 'Flat' option wasn't working because the project wasn't a Java project in eclipse's eyes.

I'd just checked out a Maven project from our SCM (svn). I noticed there was no 'J' on the project folder icon in **Package Explorer**. I then did **Right-Click -> Configure -> Convert to Maven Project** to fix.